# android email validation with non English

Tags: android, email-validation

This is the code what I wrote for email validation

> android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()

I tested Russian for email input but the result is false.
any idea?

Comment: it looks like `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` does not accept cyrillics. You will have to write cyrillic validation by yourself. You can take `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` as an example, and replace or add cyrillic characters there.

Comment: @VladMatvienko do you have working pattern tested already?

Comment: There is no valid regex pattern for validating emails ...

Comment: @Selvin so what is the solution?

Comment: @rabit, I don't have. I'd have posted answer if I had. Maibe I will try to create one.